# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget while Executing Android Expandable List

Tags: android

Based on the String in my activity iam executing   expandable list (Am retrieving all child content from the raw folder(data.txt) ) but the problem was coming while setting adapter

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


              String s11="friendly-lovable";


            temp=s11.split(delimeter);  
            for(i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
                System.out.println(temp[0]);
            System.out.println(temp[1]);
            System.out.println(temp.length);


                DataGetting();//this method for adding items to expandable List.it is running successfully
            DataGetting1();//calling all values from  raw data.txt file for first word temp[0] .it is also executing successfully 
            childAdding();//calling all values from  raw data.txt file for first word temp[1] .it is also executing successfully 

      elasricadapter=new MyExpandableListAdapter();
      //up to this executing successfully .


      setListAdapter(elasricadapter); //from this line am getting error in log cat .
```

**error is:**

```
ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(598): 355200-byte external allocation too large for this process.
 ERROR/GraphicsJNI(598): VM won't let us allocate 355200 bytes 
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(598): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(598): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gini/com.gini.Mainactivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.ExpandableListView
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(598): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.widget.ExpandableListView
: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(598): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(598):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(598):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:450)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(598):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:326)
```

So please help me any one AASP

T&R
Rajinikanth

Answer (score 1):

You should also try to test your app directly on a real device (with all the debugging tools available with the emulator), because it's possible that the Out Of Memory exception does not appear. It was the case for one of my app. But still, it does not mean that it will never happen.

Answer (score 0):

A bitmap is being processed at that stage.
This image is simply to big. There is no workaround but using a smaller image.

Comment: thanking you for responding .. But in my expandable am not using any images just am taking data from raw and am binding to child ..

Comment: Well, in that stack trace, a `Bitmap` is being decoded from a file: `android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:326)`. The stack trace also contains a reference to the line 20 of your XML. Would you post a text version of this file with the line numbers, or at least with a mark on the line 20?

Answer (score 0):

This question comes up very frequently and there are answers for it:
Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+OutOfMemoryError%3A+bitmap+size+exceeds+VM+budget